# error: declaration does not declare anything [-Werror]|

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct BO2Offsets
{
    struct Prestige
    {
        u32 offset = 0x000000;
        char data[13] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04,
                          0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
                          0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C
                        };
    };
} BO2Offsets;
```

This is a very amateur question with what I'm sure is going to be a very simple answer, but I can't resolve the problem. I have a .h file with his corresponding .cpp file, but for some reason whenever I try to compile with gcc, I keep getting errors:

> declaration does not declare anything // line 10
>   expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '**attribute**' before '=' token // line 5

I would like use BO2Offsets like that:

```
BO2Offsets BO2;
BO2.Prestige.offset;
```

EDIT2:
Resolved, thank's :)

```
typedef struct BO2Offsets BO2Offsets;
struct BO2Offsets
{
    struct Prestige
    {
        u32 offset;
        char data[13];
    } prestige;
};
```

Comment: Please read at least one book on C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using **C** compiler, but the code is **C++** (that too C++14). You need to change the compiler (or toolset), or change the code so that it compiles with C compiler.

EDIT: Which line? Does it say `struct Prestige` is not utilized?

Based on your edit:

```
 typedef struct Prestige
        {
            u32 offset = 0x000000;
            char data[13] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04,
                              0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09,
                              0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C
                            };
        } prestige; // Small letters
...
BO2Offsets BO2;
BO2.prestige.offset;
```

I've used **small letters** for the variable, so that it is clearly different from the type `Prestige`.